# Virtual infinite scrolling of large data sets

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to display a large number (*millions*) of essentially log file data in form of a table, which shows the log of a long-running process. The user should be able to scroll through the list, but the browser should only load the currently visible rows of the table.
So, essentially I know that I have at least x rows of data, potentially increasing (the number of available lines can be obtained via asking the server easily). Each row has the same height, so calculating the visible lines should be relatively easy.

The solutions I found use an array to determine the total number of entries, but this is suboptimal since it requires a *huge* array (even if I only populate the entries which are visible, the whole array gets allocated). I think arrays are used to determine changes, but the content I am using is static and thus no changes are required.

Are there any frameworks or libraries which offer such kind of large-scale data handling?

Comment: Read a file line by line obviously, keeping the least possible in memory. This seems like a serverside issue but you didn't mention what happens on that side.

Comment: The server content is saved in a database. Using a web API I can read from row x to row y and request information on how many rows there are in the database. This question is solely on the client-side, since I want to view the data with the least browser resources as possible.

Comment: It is fairly trivial clientside; say you load 20 log records initially. You scroll down, a javascript listener detects that, you load 10 more. You discard the 10 rows at the top. Scrolling up, you append 10 to the beginning, you discard the 10 rows at the bottom. It is essentially a sliding window.